# How can I vaporize metals?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, experimental-physics, computer-engineering, chemistry

What are some common ways that I can vaporize Metals into a vacuum chamber? How can I keep these Metals in a gaseous state?

Comment: There is a whole science dedicated to doing this , it's called vapor deposition or vacuum metallization. The equipment for doing it is very specialized and expensive, I hope you have a lot of money !  :-)

Comment: What amounts of metal? Why does it need to stay vaporized? For how long?

Comment: A few grams of metal need to be vaporized but only in micrograms amounts at once. It needs to be deposited in thick layers on another surface (electroplating wont work for what I need) and it only needs to be vaporized for as long as it is necessary to deposited on the other material.

Comment: What is "thick"? At some point, this may be a job for a professional-level system.

Comment: Its thickness is ~1.2 millimeters.

Comment: Please do do two things so that we can continue properly. First, I will note that one or the other or both of the answers given so far addresses your original questions to the best extent possible. Mark them as such. Secondly, open a new question. You are not interested in evaporating metals to be gases in a vacuum. You are interested in depositing millimeter thick metal layers on a substrate using methods other than electroplating.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to vaporize a metal is to create a filament of the metal. Heat the filament in the vacuum to its sublimation (vaporization) temperature. Alternatively, when the metal cannot be shaped into a filament, the metal can be encased in or painted on a "wrapper" metal. Commercial evaporators for alkali metals are designed this way. The wrapper is a thin tungsten foil encasing the alkali and having a small slit or hole in it. Heat the wrapper, and the alkali evaporates.

As to keeping a metal as a vapor, consider how to confine a metal within chamber walls AND keep it as a gas. When the walls are colder than the sublimation temperature of the metal, the instant the metal gas hits the walls, it will condense. So, as already noted, the chamber walls will have to be at least as hot as the sublimation temperature of the metal itself, if not hotter.

An alternative method to keep metal "gaseous" is to ionize the metal immediately as or immediately after it is vaporized. The metal ions can be confined within a magnetic field.

The methods to vaporize metals are relatively cost effective, well-documented, and reliable for small amounts of material. Vaporizing more than nano-gram amounts of metal heads to expensive, professional-level designs. The principles remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

vaporizing metal in a near-vacuum is a straightforward process; the simplest method is called sputtering and is one specific method of vacuum metallization as noted by William Hird above.

Keeping a vaporized metal in a gaseous state for more than a few milliseconds is a different proposition, however. For that you would need a furnace with tremendous power and extremely good insulation surrounding it.

Comment: And the vacuum....

Comment: Alternatively, you need a rarified gas state and/or the equivalent of a vacuum chamber that is big enough in dimension so as to avoid particle-particle and wall-particle collisions in the time desired to keep the particles as a gas.

Comment: And vacuum arc remelt; that is how  titanium metal is produced .